# Print arraylist in detail

Tags: arraylist, groovy

I am running an Array code as below

```
ArrayList elements= result.tools
```

When i try to print as below

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
    String value = elements.get(i);
    System.out.println("Element: " + value);
```

I only can see it printed like:
Element: UFXB-004
Element: UFXB-005
Element: UFXB-006

How can i print the full detail like eqpId, epqClass and so on for each of element?

[image]

Comment: Element class contains  eqpId, epqClass  ?result.tools returns ArrayList of Element?

Comment: the `ArrayList elements` line of code seems incomplete, you need to share the complete details

Comment: override and implement toString() method for the object you have in the Arraylist

Comment: If your `elements` list actually contains `Equipment` objects, like you show, then your code `String value = elements.get(i)` would cause a `ClassCastException`, and you wouldn't be printing anything. So which is it? Is the list a `List<Equipment>` or a `List<String>`? Well, actually, your code won't even compile, because `elements` is a *raw* list, so `String value = elements.get(i)` would fail to compile with error `Object and String not compatible`, or some such. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and **Verifiable** example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You should implements the `toString()` method in class `Equipment` like:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return this.eqpId + ", " + this.epqClass
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement toString() and append every property in that class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
        return this.eqpId + ", " + this.eqpClass + ", " + this.eqpPlatform;
}
```

If you want to use reflection, you could try this:

```
 @Override
 public String toString() {
   StringBuilder fields = new StringBuilder();
   for (Field field : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
       field.setAccessible(true);
       fields.append(field);
       fields.append(" ");
   }
   return fields;
 }
```